# Better word for "un-influenced"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to write something like "Follow your dream! Make sure it is un-influenced by the society". Is there a better word?

Here the idea is to convey that dreams should not be seeded into someone by the society.

Comment: In this specific case I'd prefer *"Make sure it is not influenced by the society"* than a different adjective. Also it'd probably be more appropriate to just say "by society" than use the definite article.

Comment: I think it sounds more natural to change the rest of the sentence: "Don't let it be influenced by society."

Comment: You could also incorporate the word "independent", as in "Make sure it is independent of societal influence" or "Make sure it is independent of societal pressure".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact word you are looking for is **unswayed** ("not moved or affected :  not influenced *unswayed by personal considerations*", [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unswayed)).

> Follow your dream! Make sure it is **unswayed** by society.

Note that I removed the article before *society*, as this is an uncountable, abstract word.

Answer (score 2):

***Immune*** — [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/immune)

> adj. 2.1 (predicative) not affected or influenced by something.
>   *"no one is **immune** to his immense charm"*

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the second sentence saying where dreams should NOT originate, maybe try an adjective to emphasise where they come from e.g.

> "Follow your **own** dreams!".

In a similar vein there are plenty of [synonyms for 'own'](https://www.google.com/search?q=synomn%20own):  personal, individual, particular, private, personalized, idiosyncratic, characteristic, unique; especial

Answer (score 2):

Not a single word answer but this may convey the meaning you are after:

> "Follow your dream **regardless** of society!".

Answer (score 1):

*Follow your dreams **irrespective of** society*

> irrespective of
>
> Not taking (something) into account; regardless of
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/fr/definition/anglais_americain/irrespective)
>
> Without considering something or being influenced by it.
>
> [Eton College p34-36](https://quizlet.com/101493784/eton-college-p-34-36-flash-cards/)

Answer (score 0):

With that quiet but **unyielding** determination, he has put his newspaper at the forefront of the battle to keep an independent and critical press alive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're implying society influences would be a negative factor:

"Follow your dream! Make sure it is **uninhibited** by the society"